# undefined value Array inside Json

Tags: json, node.js

This is my code to get logged-in user data

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  /* look at the 2nd parameter to the below call */
  let errors = [];
  if (!req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'please enter email and password');
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error_msg', 'your email or password is not correct');
      res.redirect('/login')
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      var type = user.type;
      var dt = dateTime.create();
      var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
      connection.query("update table set last_login = '"+formatted+"' where id = '"+user.id+"'", function (err, rows) {
        if(type == '0'){
          res.redirect('/login');
        }
        else if(type == '1'){
          console.log(user);
          res.cookie('user', user).redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        else{
          res.redirect('/customers');
        }
      });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

i'm try to console some data in node js and in which data is getting something like this.

```
{ 
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  username: 'tester',
  id: 9,
  password: '7ZaOhA0Q0tMTqHC8ExpOLDEdetCb3zKzQYFHIh9RpuI=',
  type: '1',
  token: 
 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImVtYWlsIjoic2l2YWFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJzaXZhYSIsImlkIjo5LCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IjdaYU9oQTBRMHRNVHFIQzhFeHBPTERFZGV0Q2Izekt6UVlGSEloOVJwdUk9IiwidHlwZSI6IjEiLCJ0b2tlbiI6IiJ9LCJpYXQiOjE1MzQ1Njg3NjEsImV4cCI6MTUzNDU3MTc2MX0._3AspvfLO2K46OVilqsLtfiRcZTG2ZYvGJWe6jaQ3ZA',
  customers: undefined 
}
```

now i want to display customers field data which is contain data like this abc,xyz,pqr and it seems undefined.
so how can i get data instead of undefined and please tell me the reason behind undefined value if you know

Thank you in advance your help make my day brighter.

Comment: Without seeing ur code how can we decide what's going wrong

Comment: Okay i will edit my post and add code

Comment: ya just edit nd add the code

Comment: In your code, you are printing `user.customers` but in the response object, it looks like you have pasted `user` object, I'm not sure... am I right??

Comment: Yes @MadMan you right i have solved that but let me know you get my error or not??

Comment: i want to display array comma separate value from DB instead of undefined.

Comment: I can see the updated code. Can you try one thing..?? Try printing `user.customers` right after `passport.authenticate(...` this line. and tell me the output. It has to be `undefined`.

Comment: I know, it should be array of `customer` object. But plz check above step first to get the error scope.

Comment: Okay @MadMan i tried but  it still display only this undefined as value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178240/discussion-between-mad-man-and-niket-joshi).

Comment: @MadMan i have solve my error thank you for your time which you spent for error resolving.